# How to create command to send me text message as to whether it failed or passed?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, tcsh

I am trying to create a command that will send me a text message whether it passed or failed.

So far my command looks like this:

```
command && echo OK || echo Failed | echo ' 'at `date | sendmail 5556667777@vtext.com
```

So when the text passes I would like it to send me a text (by sending me an email) and the text should read as follows:

> OK at March 2 2:37pm

and when the test fails it should text me this:

> Failed at March 2 2:37pm.

I am not sure how to concatenate the `echo` outputs correctly and I'm hoping someone knows where my problem lies. The shell is `tcsh`.

EDIT:

For something like 'ls' I want the directories listed in the terminal, but I want the "Ok" or "fail" to go to the 'sendmail" part. So all commands should print to the terminal as usual, but send the 'failed' or 'ok' part to the sendmail portion.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, i got "illegal variable name". I am trying to do this on the command line btw. TCSH shell.

Answer (score 0):

OP's comment:

> For something like `ls` I want the directories listed in the terminal, but I want the "Ok" or "fail" to go to the `sendmail` part.

I can't do this in `tcsh`. This should work in `bash`:

```
your_command ; { [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo -n OK || echo -n Failed ; echo " at `date`" ; } | …
```

**I hope someone will take it from here, port the above line to `tcsh` and write a better answer.**

The best I can think of is a `bash` script, if only you have `bash` on the machine. The point is you can run such a script from `tcsh`. This is quick and dirty script:

```
#!/bin/bash
"$@"
{ [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo -n OK || echo -n Failed ; echo " at `date`" ; } | sendmail 5556667777@vtext.com
```

Modify the shebang if you need to. Save this piece of code to a file (e.g. `sendstatus.sh`), make it executable with `chmod`, then use it like this:

```
./sendstatus.sh your_command
./sendstatus.sh your_command --with option -s
./sendstatus.sh ls
./sendstatus.sh ls -sl
```

The fixes:

- `echo -n` causes the next `echo` to continue in the same line;
- the last `echo` doesn't read from the pipe because it had no sense;
- `date` is inside ` marks (command substitution);
- commands are grouped by `{}` delimiters so their output is passed to the final `|` altogether.

Comment: I get: {: Command not found.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either. So when it passes, it is passing the output of the command as well, I just want the "ok at date" or "failed at date" part

Comment: @Veridian How about now?

Comment: I haven't checked it yet, but from looking at it it looks like all output of the command will be suppressed. For something like 'ls' I want the directories listed in the terminal, but I want the "Ok" or "fail" to go to the 'sendmail" part.

Comment: @Veridian I give up. See my final answer. You should edit your question and place all your wishes there (don't expect users to read all the comments; the question should be self-explanatory). Good luck.

Comment: @Veridian Frankly I don't think the question deserves upvoting (yet). It seemed the problem was "how to concatenate the `echo` outputs correctly". My answer (previous version targeted at `tcsh`) has already solved this; it has also corrected command substitution syntax. Then you concentrated on the first command output. I think here should be at least two separate questions: this one about `echo` outputs, the second about the first command output. If you want to keep it all here, you should improve the question as I told you. I find expecting my upvote while not following my advice kinda rude.

Comment: @Veridian One more thing, about "additional exposure": your edit will bump the question to the top of the main page.

Comment: That's unfortunate that you interpreted it that way. I modified the equation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56319/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-veridian).